# Select columns in sql with respect to time shifts

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datatable, procedure

we have people in three shifts (each shift people work eight hours) per day. lets say when some work arises it is assigned to respective shift people.

we have following data in oracle database.

| Task | Shift_1 | Shift_2 | Shift_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | WorkGroup1 | WorkGroup2 | WorkGroup3 |
| Task2 | WorkGroup1 | WorkGroup2 | WorkGroup3 |

we want to get the data from above table like below

**when time is (00-08 HRS)** then

```
select Task,Shift_1 from DB;
```

**when time is (09-16 HRS)** then

```
select Task,Shift_2 from DB;
```

**when time is (17-00 HRS)** then
select Task,Shift_3 from DB;

can we optimize the above three queries as one ? that one query will be used in one procedure. and it will be totally automated

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select task,
       (case when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') < '00:08'
             then shift_1
             when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI') < '00:15'
             then shift_2
             else shift_3
        end) as shift
from db;
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally, what you said:

```
select task,
  case when to_char(sysdate, 'hh24mi') between '0000' and '0800' then shift_1
       when to_char(sysdate, 'hh24mi') between '0801' and '1600' then shift_2
       when to_char(sysdate, 'hh24mi') between '1601' and '2359' then shift_3
  end as shift
from db
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case expression as follows:

```
Select task,
       case when to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') <= 8 then shift_1
            When to_char(sysdate, 'HH24') <= 16 then shift_2
            Else shift_3 
       end as shift
  From your_table
```

**Note**: you forgot to give shift to 08-09 time. I gave `shift_1` to mentioned time.